# How to organize dependencies for C++ project in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse

What's the recommended way to import dependencies for a C++ project in Eclipse?

For example, say I'm making a library and the project looks like

```
MyLib
- MyLib.cpp
```

Now I want to add the Lua library which I guess could just be under my project. But the problem is it needs it's own build formula which it includes as a makefile

```
MyLib
- MyLib.cpp
- Lua
-- lua.h
-- lua.c
-- Makefile
-- lua.a
```

Or I can import Lua into a new project and have my library reference it in several ways to find the header, the library and so on

```
MyLib
- MyLib.cpp
Lua
- lua.h
- lua.c
- Makefile
- lua.a
```

The problem here is it takes a lot of fiddling with the build setups and after I get it right I'd like to be able to export everything someone needs to build my library so someone else can work on it. (Or even just so I can work on it on another system.)

I've seen a similar question about organizing Java projects and in that case they say to make a super project with other projects under it. But this advice assumes you're using Maven and I think the answer may be different for a C++ project. What is your advice?

Comment: I wouldn't use eclipse for c++ if I were you

Comment: Steve, but to use, if you are not working under windows ? Do you have any advices ?

Comment: @steve not my choice but some vender foisting.

Comment: @wiesniak well...no. I usually develop under windows and then make final test on other platforms

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest do external build system with for example make or even better cmake, and import project into Eclipse.
I usually works like that and that's fine solution. 
You can clean/build your project by mouse from eclipse, debug and etc, but you just have to care about your build system by yourself. Your code can compile without Eclipse, with standard tools, which is big advantage.

If you know better solution I will very glad to hear :-)

Comment: A fine answer but woe is me that the Advantest corporation has contrived to bind an inscrutable registration mechanism under closed sources into the dark heart of Eclipse itself. Would that I could escape to the command line but it is like a lost city in which the hardware will take no notice of my compilations.

Comment: with cmake you can generate eclipse CDT project makefile project and then import it to Eclipse. You still have to maintain your Cmake files when adding some new source, however Eclipse threats such project as its created by its own.